# Adjusting div container's size and position according to page size

Tags: html, css

Sorry for bad english in advance. English is my second language and my question may not be worded clearly.

I'm trying to make a simple website with a nintendo switch image in the middle of the page as the background. The switch image was found from pixabay and is free to use.

Anywas, I was trying to select the div container's size and position so that it represents only the "screen" of the switch. When the switch is interacted - ex. screen is turned on, a game is selected, etc. only the screen div should be reactive and change its visual accordingly.

However, I have a problem with the selected div section when zooming in/out, adjusting page size, and when I open it from a different browser. The div section perfectly fits to the switch screen when I open it from chrome, at 100% zoomed in.
But when I zoom in or out, the div section just stays still and doesn't adjust its size. When I adjust the page size, the div section adjust its size but won't fit to the screen.

**html:**

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="">
    </script>
    <title>
    </title>

    <body>
        <div class="switchContainer">
            <img src="images/nintendo_switch.png" alt="">
            <div class="screenOn">
            </div> 
        </div>     
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**css:**

```
.switchContainer {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
.switchContainer img {
    position: absolute; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.screenOn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 218px;
    left: 371px;
    width: 730px;
    height: 408px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.screenOn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
}
```

"screenOn" is the div that represents the screen of the switch.

I tried using vh and vw or px instead of %, tried setting position to relative instead of absolute, tried taking screenOn div outside the "switchContainer" in case the positioning of "switchContainer" was messing with "screenOn", but none of these attempts worked.

I even tried fixing my code after asking chat GPT about it but it was no use.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just a bit off with centering and backgrounds, also a bit excessive in HTML.

Minimal working example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#switch {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background: url(https://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/nintendo-switch-firmware-update-8.0.jpg) no-repeat 50% / contain;
}

#screen {
  width: 40%;
  height: 44%;
  background: url(https://i.giphy.com/media/26u4957hCLCwMZWco/giphy.webp) 50% / cover;
  border-radius:
}
```

```html
<div id="switch">
  <div id="screen"></div>
</div>
```